# Google Sheets Query Searching?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to run a Query on some data that's being imported, and have it only Bring data over that matches the Email in the document.

This is my code:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID REMOVED","'Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$O"),"SElECT * WHERE Col15 = 'TEST'",1)
```

Where it says TEST, I have a Script that pulls the Email, and places it in `=YTD!B21`

How can I get the Query to Import only the ranges that have the Attached Email?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, after doing a lot of research.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID REMOVED","'Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$O"),"SElECT * WHERE Col15 contains '"&YTD!B21&"'",1)
```